# Create TypeLiteral from generic method parameterType

Tags: java, guice

Using : Guice 3

I would like to know how to create a `TypeLiteral` from a generic method parameterType (**to inject it with an injector**).

Here is an example :

Context :

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Set<String>>(){}).toInstance(x);
bind(new TypeLiteral<Set<Integer>>(){}).annotatedWith(INJECTOR.class).toInstance(y);
```

---

```
public class Foo
{

public void bar(Injector injector, Set<String> param, @INJECTOR Set<Integer> value)
{
    //...
}

}
```

---

```
public class Example
{
@Inject
Injector injector;

public void methodInjector()
{
    Method[] fooMethods = Foo.class.getMethods();
    for(Method m : fooMethods)
    {
        for(Class<?> c : m.getParameter.getParameterTypes())
        {
            Object o = injector.getInstance(c); 

            /*
              this work for simple Type like "Injector" but 
              don't work for generic type (Set<String>, List<Set<String>>, ...).
            */
        }
    }

}

}
```

Obviously injecting `java.util.Set` don't work in my case... Maybe there is a trick with TypeLiteral to do it...

I hope that my explanation is clear,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using [TypeLiteral.getParameterTypes(Member)](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html#getParameterTypes%28java.lang.reflect.Member%29)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you correctly [here](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/02/07/acessing-generic-types-at-runtime-in-java/) you have explained how accessing generic types at runtime. If you want to get parameter type of all classes it is [impossible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: It could be possible cause Guice may use it when methods are annotated with @Inject annotation, no ?